# password protect apache vhost + reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, password, reverse-proxy, virtualhost

I wish to create a password protected vhost for selected clients (clients.mysite.com)

We have a windows reverse proxy with some vhosts (www, static, secure). I am not using htaccess files as this is a reverse proxy and website is served by another back end server

How could I set up a password? I am using .conf files for our vhosts

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine it could be done the same way you would protect a normal directory

```
<VirtualHost site:80>
    ServerName ...
    <Location /proxypath/>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Files"
        AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
        Require user rbowen
    </Location>

    ProxyPass /proxypath/ ...
</VirtualHost >
```

Then use the htpasswd utility to generate a .htpasswd file

Comment: Thank for your help, but Apache won't restart with this...
    <virtualHost *>
    ServerName test3.mysite.com
    ServerAlias  test3.mysite.com
    ServerAlias 192.168.1.250
    ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.com
    DirectoryIndex index.htm
    ProxyPass /cgi-vel/web/  http://localhost:82/cgi-vel/web/ keepalive=on  
    ProxyPass /  http://localhost:82/cgi-vel/web/ keepalive=on  
    ProxyPassReverse /  http://localhost:82/cgi-vel/web/ keepalive=on 
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ErrorLog "logs/test_web_error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/test_web-access.log" combined 

    </virtualHost>

Comment: @RaulTaboraz Does it give you an error?

Comment: yes, apache does not start... I am sorry for delay and wrong code. I have really solved today, adding password required to "static" vhost, not reverse proxy. Thank you anyway